# C# DirectoryEntry Properties Value Change

Tags: c#, .net, directoryentry, userprincipal

I want to use C# to

1. Create a new user.
2. Add it to "Users" group
3. Enable Dial-in Remote Network Permission
4. Disable remote control

My code:

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine);
UserPrincipal newuser = new UserPrincipal(ctx, "newuser", "password", true);
newuser.Save();

GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx,"Users");

using (DirectoryEntry groupEntry = group.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry )
using (DirectoryEntry userEntry = newuser.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry)
{
    groupEntry.Invoke( "Add", new object[] { userEntry.Path } );
    userEntry.RefreshCache();

    userEntry.Properties["msNPAllowDialin"].Value = true;
    userEntry.Properties["msTSRemoteControl"].Value = false;

    userEntry.CommitChanges();
}
```

The account creation and user group process works fine, however,

```
userEntry.Properties["msNPAllowDialin"].Value = true;
userEntry.Properties["msTSRemoteControl"].Value = false;
```

Both generates an error

> The directory property cannot be found in the cache

I have spent 2 hours Googling but still can't find any working solutions.

Comment: seem to me that you are looking for a property that doesn't exist in LDAP. Where you running this code? server details?

Comment: I'm running Windows server 2016 but i just want to create local users that can access the server's VPN  that's all.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a local computer account (`ContextType.Machine`) but then trying to set properties that are specific to Active Directory user accounts. That won't work.

If you want to restrict them from the server's VPN, then that depends on what kind of VPN you're using.